# Forming String from Struct via CustomStringConvertible

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to build a URL query as something similar

`limit=20&offset=0`

if there is no `limit` then URL query should look like

`offset=0`

I tried to form the string as follows, but my struct items are optionals; therefore, I am confused to come up with a string.

```
struct Filter {
  var limit: Int?
  var offset: Int?
}

extension Filter:CustomStringConvertible {
  var description: String {
    return "limit=\(limit)&offset=\(offset)"
  }
}
```

Comment: what if `offset` is nil?  Regardless, you can't do it in a one liner. You will need to conditionally unwrap and construct the string

Comment: Wouldn't this be much easier / cleaner using `URLComponent`s?

Comment: @Gereon, would you mind to illustrate your suggestion please?

Comment: @Paulw11, if both are nil, then return an empty String.

Comment: @casillas `URLComponents` are well documented, and you can find may tutorials online.

Comment: Use URLComponents. But for your logic, as said, not in oneline: `var str: String = ""; if let limit = limit { str.append("limit=\(limit") } etc.`

Comment: The answer by @witek spells out what I would have suggested, that's essentially how I would implement this as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to stick to the String version, here is my take:

```swift
extension Filter: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        [
            limit.map { "limit=\($0)" },
            offset.map { "offset=\($0)" }
        ].compactMap { $0 }.joined(separator: "&")
    }
}
```

But as there already are comments that guide you toward the good solution, I figured I might provide you with an example. Let's start with building query items for the `Filter` object.

```swift
extension Filter {
    var queryItems: [URLQueryItem] {
        var items = [URLQueryItem]()
        if let limit = limit {
            items.append(URLQueryItem(name: "limit", value: limit))
        }
        if let offset = offset {
            items.append(URLQueryItem(name: "offset", value: offset))
        }
        return items
    }
}
```

and now its super easy to build URL using `URLComponents`

```swift
let filter: Filter

var components = URLComponents()
components.scheme = "https" // example scheme
components.host = "api.github.com" // example url
components.path = "/search/repositories" // example path
components.queryItems = filter.queryItems

let url = components.url
```

John Sundell has a great article on [Constructing URLs in Swift](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/constructing-urls-in-swift/)